# Как заставить телеграмм воспринимать команду /faq именно как команду, а не как пользовательское сообщение?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Пишу бота на Python. Бот говорит пользователю:

Для возврата средств - напишите реквизиты для оплаты. Если у Вас остались вопросы нажмите /faq.

Если пользователь пишет что угодно - бот отвечает - спасибо за Ваше сообщение! Если тыкает на /faq - должна вызваться эта команда. А у меня почему то всё равно пишет - спасибо за Ваше сообщение! Помогите пожалуйста исправить(
Я совсем новичок. Понимаю, что это вроде можно реализовать через if else, но у меня не получается.

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Как мне запросить возврат средств?</b>',parse_mode='html')
sendrequest = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<i>Для возврата средств - напишите реквизиты для оплаты. Если у Вас остались вопросы нажмите /faq.</i>', parse_mode='html')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<i> Постарайтесь больше не совершать ошибочные платежи. </i>',parse_mode='html')


bot.register_next_step_handler(sendrequest, paymentrequesresieved)         
    
def paymentrequesresieved (message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<b>Cпасибо за Ваше сообщение!</b>',parse_mode='html')  
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['faq'])
def faq(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>вопрос1</b>', parse_mode='html')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'<i>Ответ1</i>', parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: Стоит тогда углубиться в изучении языка. Это элементарные вещи. Тебе всё равно понадобятся и условия и циклы и многое другое. Выведи в консоль объект `message`, посмотри в чём отличие команд от текста, на этом и ставь условия.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что обработчик текстовых сообщений расположен выше, чем обработчик комманды /faq. Поменяйте их местами и все будет работать

Comment: Ну а вообще, не стоит начинать учить программирование с написания телеграм ботов. Во-первых, вы не сможете написать нормального бота, который бы работал без циклов и условий. Во-вторых, изучать программирование надо с основ, иначе вы по каждой мелкой проблеме будете писать на stackoverflow